# Can I show the individual messages of a thread in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

Is there a setting or plugin that allows me to unfold the individual messages of a Gmail thread in the message list?

Example:

```
Thread 1 (unfolded)
>>> Message 1
>>> Message 2
>>> Message 3
Thread 2 (folded)
Thread 3 (unfolded)
>>> Message 1
>>> Message 2
```

I am looking for something similar to [Outlook](http://tr1.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2015/05/07/f8012321-f495-11e4-940f-14feb5cc3d2a/12260.jpg).
In that example the third thread from the top is folded out, showing an e-mail from Susan and an e-mail from Mary.

Comment: You can get pretty close to this with Google Inbox. Click on a conversation, and it will expand, showing the subject line _and_ the first (or so) lines of the body of each message. https://www.google.com/inbox

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I use inbox on my personal account, but unfortunately my admin has disabled it on my work Gmail...

Comment: I'm afraid Gmail, by itself, won't do what you want. You'll need a userscript or some other third-party solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings and select "Conversation View" and click save.

Comment: That doesn't allow for folding/unfolding of conversations into separate messages.